# Pandas read csv using wild card pattern for selecting columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, glob

I have 3 csv files

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11,11,11],'Age':[23,25,28],'Summary':['Test','Test1','Test2']})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [21,22,51],'Age':[26,29,22],'Order Summary':['Tep','Tst1','Tt2'],'Order Summary2':['ppp','Ttt','Tfsa']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [31,31,41],'Age':[27,20,21],'Order Summary':['Tet','Tt1','Tt2'],'Order Summary1':['Tet','Tt1','Tt2']})
```

I would like to read all those csv files and create one dataframe.

However, I would like to read only two columns for each file and their names are bit different. I would like to create one final dataframe with two columns `person_id` and `Summary` (also named as `Order Summary` in other csv files)

I don't wish to read `Age`, `Order Summary1` or `Order Summary2` columns for other csv files.

**Basically use regex/pattern matching only to read `Summary|Order Summary` columns while creating final dataframe**

I was trying something like below from SO post

```
col_list = ["person_id", "Summary"]  # but here i don't know how to use regex
files = glob.glob("file*.csv")
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f,usecols = col_list, header=None, sep=";") for f in files]

meddata = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
```

Can help me on how to use regex to select columns while reading csvs?

I expect my final dataframe to have columns like as shown below you can see how only those 2 required columns from each csv file are selected and concatenated)

```
Person_id   Summary
11           Test    
11           Test1
11           Test2
21           Tep
22           Tst1
51           Tt2 
31           Tet
31           Tt1
41           Tt2
```

Comment: I only want `Order Summary`. All the files have either `Summary` or `Order Summary`. We don't care about `Order Summary 1` or `Order Summary 2`. If you see `df1` and `df2`, you can see that it has `Order Summary` as well as `Order Summary2`. I only want `Order Summary`. Hope this helos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplier is rename columns `Order Summary` first and then selecting only expected 2 columns:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, sep=";").rename(columns={'Order Summary':'Summary'})[['person_id','Summary']]
       for f in files]
```

Old answer:

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) by regex for match `person_id` and `Summary` with end of strings values:

```
print (df.filter(regex='person_id|Summary$'))
   person_id Summary
0         11    Test
1         11   Test1
2         11   Test2

print (df1.filter(regex='person_id|Summary$'))
  person_id Order Summary
0         21           Tep
1         22          Tst1
2         51           Tt2

print (df2.filter(regex='person_id|Summary$'))
   person_id Order Summary
0         31           Tet
1         31           Tt1
2         41           Tt2
```

Another idea is use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) by list of possible values:

```
print (df[df.columns.intersection(['person_id', 'Summary', 'Order Summary'])])
print (df1[df1.columns.intersection(['person_id', 'Summary', 'Order Summary'])])
print (df2[df2.columns.intersection(['person_id', 'Summary', 'Order Summary'])])
```

So in your solution also add `rename` for output 2 columns DataFrame:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, sep=";").filter(regex='person_id|Summary$').rename(columns={'Order Summary':'Summary'})
       for f in files]
```

For second need:

```
dfs = []       
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";")
    df1 = df[df.columns.intersection(['person_id', 'Summary', 'Order Summary'])].rename(columns={'Order Summary':'Summary'})
    dfs.append(df1)
```

Comment: Since you use filter, there is no need of `usecols` paramter. Right?

Comment: @TheGreat - There are cvs headers?

Comment: Yes. My csv file contains column names

Comment: @TheGreat - You are right, remove it. Also header=None

Comment: When I test by using one csv file with million records, why does this line `df = [pd.read_csv(f, sep=";").filter(regex='person_id|Summary$') for f in files]` produce the `df` as `list` type?  Shouldn't it be dataframe type?

Comment: @TheGreat - It is list of DataFrames, what is `for df in dfs: print (type(df))` ?

Comment: @TheGreat - Answer was improved for `rename` - it change columns names `Order Summary` to `Summary` for final output `'person_id', 'Summary'` columns

Answer (score 2):

Read everythin. You can later select the columns from each DF by checking if they are on the list of permitted columns, e.g.:

```
permitted = ['person_id', 'Summary', 'Order Summary']
df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(permitted)]
#   person_id Summary
#0         11    Test
#1         11   Test1
#2         11   Test2
```